# WebDev20 not saving data in DB when used in Dynamic php mode

Tags: php, windev

We are just getting started with WebDev (WinDev for Web).

I am trying to build a small sample web app using Dynamic PHP mode.

Everything seems to work well but all of a sudden now the web app is not able to save the data entered by user in a form.

When we try to save data to DB (MySQL) blank record gets added.

There are not errors when we run the app.

Here is the code that saved user entered data to MySQL.

```
HReset(customer_master)
customer_master.cm_city = EDT_CustomerCity
customer_master.cm_email_id = EDT_CustomerEmail
customer_master.cm_mobile = EDT_CustomerMobile
customer_master.cm_name = EDT_CustomerName
HAdd(customer_master)
```

All the data from Form comes up blank. Don't know as to why?

Please help sort this out.

TIA

Yogi Yang

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an error message when you execute Hadd() function ?

```
HReset(customer_master)
customer_master.cm_city = EDT_CustomerCity
customer_master.cm_email_id = EDT_CustomerEmail
customer_master.cm_mobile = EDT_CustomerMobile
customer_master.cm_name = EDT_CustomerName
IF HAdd(customer_master) = False Then
   Error("HFSQL error: " + [HErrorInfo][1]())
END
```

Answer (score 0):

try HRAZ(customer_master) , because HReset is setting all fields blank